# Anchor link not working on desktop but works on mobile

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a link on this page: http://www.appetiteforexcellence.com/young-chef/ within the text on the page (the word "years") which does not actually link through to the desired page on desktop view but works on mobile.
When inspecting element I can see the anchor tags but can't seem to get it working.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: your `div` with the class of row which should be below your text covers the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping the following div in a row class:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 article-content page-content">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I had the same issue... adding a wrapper fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

```
.page-id-98  .white-container .page-content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1
}
```

should fix it.

It was overlapped by the next `.row` and clicks didn't get to it. Alternatively, if you don't need `pointer-events` on the following `.row`, you could set `pointer-events:none` on it, to allow `click` events to pass through, like this:

```
.page-id-98  .white-container .page-content + .row {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Note this second code-block is alternative to first, not cumulative (you don't need both). And I believe first one is better (less possible complications).

---

Above I tried to explain why your link didn't work, so you know how to debug it next time you run into this type of problems. But the practical solution is to wrap your column in a `.row`, as others suggested. The main reason being that Bootstrap recommends all `[class^="col-"]`s should be immediate children of `.row`s. If they aren't you'll run into negative margins problems and your content will develop hard to debug horizontal scrollbars at widths from 992px to 1022px and from 768px to 798px.

Comment: don't this is a good solution, when you could just wrap the column in a row-tag.

Comment: I believe markup changes should only be proposed when a CSS solution is not possible, kkreft. Following your priciple, I should propose a website redesign. Thanks for down-voting a perfectly valid CSS solution because it does not suggest markup changes.

Comment: With a CSS solution you can cover the problem, but you don't fix it. There is a clear error in the HTML markup so it is the right place to tackle the problem at its roots, in my opinion. If you think that adding a bootstrap row-wrapper is a website-redesign then yes.

Comment: Perhaps you should have taken the time to explain why placing the column into a row is preferred. SO is more about trying to explain principles than providing solutions without explaining why they are good. A happy new year!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, using a row wrapper didn't work for me. What I did was giving the div a 'position' and giving it z-index of 2. That worked fine!
Like this:

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 article-content page-content" style="position:relative; z-index:2">...</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add the missing `<div class="row">`-Wrapper as I have shown below:

```html
<div class="white-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 article-content page-content">
        <p style="text-align: left;">Here you will find all the information regarding Electrolux Australian Young Chef and this years program. to find out more about our past young chefs, click on the <a href="http://www.appetiteforexcellence.com/inspiration-series-peter-doyle/" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'outbound-article-int', 'http://www.appetiteforexcellence.com/inspiration-series-peter-doyle/', 'years ']);"
        title="what does hospitality mean to Peter Doyle?">years </a>below.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="homepage-page-item small-item">
          <a href="http://www.appetiteforexcellence.com/about-young-chef/">
            <img width="315" height="210" src="http://www.appetiteforexcellence.com/appetite/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/about-young-excellence-315x210.jpg" class="attachment-home-thumb wp-post-image" alt="2016 cul" /> <span>about young chef</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```